# how to estimate the detailed convergence rate in helly's theorem (probability)?

Tags: probability, statistics, weak-convergence

We all know one of the versions of **Helly's theorem** in probability course (c.f. the book 'Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics', page 352. See as follows):

Let $f(x)$ be the continuous function, and let the sequences of the non-decreasing uniformly bounded functions: $F_1(x), F_2(x), ... , F_n(x),...$ converge weakly to the function $F(x)$ on some finite interval $a\leq x \leq b$. Then

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{a}^b f(x) d F_n (x) = \int_{a}^b f(x) d F (x)$.

My question is: How can we estimate **the detailed convergence rate of the above convergence rate, i.e., w.r.t the sample $n$**? Do we have any corresponding tools? Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the context, it's probably difficult to say anything general about the convergence rate. But 
a)
$|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dF_{n}(x)-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dF(x)|\\
\leq \sup|f(x)|*||\mu_{n}-\mu||_{TV}$, 
where $||\mu_{n}-\mu||_{TV}$ is the total variation distance between
the measures corresponding to the distribution functions. In specific
situations, the total variation distance can be bounded.

b) if $f$ is smooth and compactly supported and let $supp(f)\subset (a,b)$, then an integration by parts shows that

$|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dF_{n}(x)-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dF(x)|\\
=|\int_{a}^{b}f^{'}(x)F_{n}(x)dx-\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)F(x)dx|\\
\leq \sup|f^{'}(x)|*\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|F_{n}(x)-F(x)|*(b-a)\\
\leq \sup|f^{'}(x)|*\sup|F_{n}(x)-F(x)|*(b-a)$

$\sup|F_{n}(x)-F(x)|$ is called the Kolmogrov-Smirnov distance and in specific situations, it can be bounded.

c) Under the same assumptions in (b) and assume the measures corresponding to the distribution function are probabability measures. Then

$|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dF_{n}(x)-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dF(x)|\\
= |E[f(X_{n})] - E[f(X)]|\\
\leq \sup |f^{'}(x)| E[|X_{n} - X|]
$

where in the last step, I constructed a "coupling" between $X_{n}$ and $X$ (a joint distribution having the correct marginals). Certainly, I can take $\inf$ over all couplings to make the bound tight and that will give

$|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dF_{n}(x)-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dF(x)|\\
\leq \sup |f^{'}(x)| \inf_{\text{all coupling of $X_{n}$ and X}}E[|X_{n} - X|]\\
=  \sup |f^{'}(x)|*Wasserstein-distance(X_{n},X)
$

The wassertein-distance can also be bounded in many cases

d) Now let's consider the setting in the central limit theorem where $F_n$ is the distribution function of the rescaled sums and $F$ the distribution function of the standard normal. Then the Berry-Esseen theorem gives precisely a bound of the Kolmogrov-Sirnov distance as $O(1/{\sqrt{n}})$ (checkout the wiki). In fact, the total variation distance can also be bounded, checkout the papers by Sergey Bobkov.

Comment: I really really appreciate your nice answer! Your d) inspires me. In fact, I just wanna estimate the convergence rate of the expectation of a sequence of square errors. (mainly use 'Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics' page 14, Theorem A), and Helly's theorem is the main part of it.

Comment: In this sense, it's possible for me to provide some more detailed non-asymptotic results, by a 'strengthened' Helly's theorem.  If I finally complete the proof, I will thank you for your help in the acknowledgments paper section.

Comment: I suggest you looking at the proof of Berry-esseen, which essentially says that if you know some convergence rate of the characteristic functions, then you can say something about the rate of convergence of the K-S distance and the proof strategy is not limited to the CLT setting. Glad that I can help